# Hadamard Product inside a norm

Tags: normed-spaces, hadamard-product

Is it true to say $\|A\circ B\| \le \|A\| \|B\|$? $\circ$ is the Hadamard product.

Comment: The inequality you mentioned is Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, and it is valid for any Vector Space equipped with an inner product.

Comment: @MubarakAlsaeedi:  the Hadamard product is not an inner product